# How to get using PowerShell privateMomerySet and PID passing service path as parameter?

Tags: powershell

maybe will be useful, as an example for Zabbix. The main problem service exe file name is the same, zabbix can get this date for each service

hope will be helpfull

```
$servicePath =$args[0]
get-process |  where {$_.Path -eq $servicePath} | Format-Table `
    @{Label = "Private Working Set";Expression = {$ProcessID = $_.ID; [math]::Round((gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | ? {$_.IDprocess -eq $ProcessID }).WorkingSetPrivate / 1mb, 0) }},
    @{Label = "State";Expression = {$ProcessID = $_.ID;Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "ProcessId='$ProcessID'"  |  select State -ExpandProperty State }},
    Path, ID -AutoSize
```

Comment: .\someScriptName.ps1 "F:\MyFolder\myservice.exe"

Comment: What... is the question?